# How may i redesign three binary relation signs?

Tags: fonts, symbols, arrows

Consider the three binary relation signs in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\begin{document}

$\vdash$

$\Vdash$

$\Vvdash$

\end{document}
```

How may I close the spaces between the vertical bars in the two last relation signs so that in the second the horisontal line protrudes from a rectangle and in the the third it protrudes from two aligned rectangles? How do I put horisontal bars on the vertical bar of the first binary relation sign so it is as the newly formed second relation sign without its leftmost vertical bar?

It will be useful if the solution allows adjustments.

Here is a dropbox-link to an amateurish drawing that suggests what I attempt to describe:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xbujdv3cqwy9u5q/20150731_004151.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Could you draw a picture of what you are aiming for? Part of my confusion is that these symbols are not arrows. I guess you just mean the horizontal lines?

Comment: Yes, I mean horisontal lines and will edit. I do not know how to draw.

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how to draw here or a more general inability to draw? I can sympathise with either, especially the latter. But a rough sketch would do - it is, as far as I can tell, only a matter of boxes and lines so it shouldn't take too much artistic talent? If the former, you can scan a sketch and upload it. Or you can fake something in a drawing programme or with TeX or even with ASCII art.

Comment: @cfr In the second case the resulting binary sign is a rectangle with a horisontal hyphen protruding from the middle of the right hand side of the rectangle. I hope that is precise enough.

Comment: I may draw on a piece of paper and then take a photograph and then save it in dropbox and then link to dropbox. Is that a useful procedure?

Comment: I am confused too. Do you mean something like this (this is just to be sure, not a proper solution): `\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}

\rule[-1.5ex]{2pt}{3ex}\rule{6pt}{0.4pt}

\rule[-1.5ex]{2pt}{3ex}\kern1pt\rule[-1.5ex]{2pt}{3ex}\rule{6pt}{0.4pt}

\end{document}`

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal I think that's really useful. Draw and upload.

Comment: Done: https://www.dropbox.com/home/Photos?preview=20150731_004151.jpg

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina The answer to your question is "no", as you may see.

Comment: Not everybody subscribes to dropbox. You can add the picture to the question

Comment: I can't view it without logging in? Oh well. Back to guessing.

Comment: @cfr I logged in and even then I couldn't see the image.

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal, you have to put the image in your Public folder within Dropbox and then get a link for it from there. That way Dropbox non-users can access it. But better yet, just add the picture to the question (Ctrl/Cmd+G).

Comment: I now added the public dropbox link. Hopefully that will be helpful.

Comment: @egreg I edited as above.

Comment: @cfr I edited as above

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina I edited as above

Comment: It would be better to just post the image here. However, there also seem to be unstated requirements which you haven't specified and which I'm not at all clear about. For example, that a solution not use the `turnstile` package. If that's a requirement, you need to explain that in your question. (Presumably if `turnstile` is out, other things are out, too. But what?) Only please make clear that you are adding information as an edit so that existing answers do not look like mere idiocies.

Comment: By the way, I still can't view your image unless it is supposed to be an entirely white space (which is what I see).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\usepackage{pict2e}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cvdash}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\cvd@sh\relax}
}

\newcommand{\cvd@sh}[2]{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\vdash$}%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{1.1\wd\z@}%
  \begin{picture}(1,0.75)
  \roundcap\roundjoin
  \polyline(0.125,0)(0.4,0)(0.4,0.75)(0.125,0.75)
  \polyline(0.4,0.375)(0.925,0.375)
  \end{picture}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\cVdash}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\cVd@sh\relax}
}
\newcommand{\cVd@sh}[2]{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\vdash$}%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{1.1\wd\z@}%
  \begin{picture}(1,0.75)
  \roundcap\roundjoin
  \polyline(0.125,0)(0.4,0)(0.4,0.75)(0.125,0.75)(0.125,0)
  \polyline(0.4,0.375)(0.925,0.375)
  \end{picture}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\cVvdash}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\cVvd@sh\relax}%
}

\newcommand{\cVvd@sh}[2]{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\vdash$}%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{1.1\wd\z@}%
  \begin{picture}(1,0.75)
  \roundcap\roundjoin
  \polyline(0.125,0)(0.55,0)(0.55,0.75)(0.125,0.75)(0.125,0)
  \polyline(.3375,0)(.3375,0.75)
  \polyline(0.6,0.375)(0.925,0.375)
  \end{picture}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\vdash\cvdash$

$\Vdash\cVdash$

$\Vvdash\cVvdash$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How may I define the variants of $\nvdash$, $\nVdash$ and a corresponing strike through for $\Vvdash$?

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal Sorry, but this is something too large for being added here.

Comment: I am now (temporarily?) using the cancel package. Are there better solutions that merit a question?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a version based on the `turnstile` package. On the left are the standard versions of the three turnstiles you used in the question. On the right are versions using a modified version of the package's `\makever` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{turnstile,calc}
\newcommand\mysststile{% single vertical with fins pointing backwards
  \let\oldmakever\makever
  \let\makever\mymakever
  \sststile{}{}%
  \let\makever\oldmakever}
\newcommand\mydststile{% double turnstile with closed top
  \let\oldmakever\makever
  \let\makever\mymakever
  \dststile{}{}%
  \let\makever\oldmakever}
\newcommand\mytststile{% triple turnstile with closed top
  \let\oldmakever\makever
  \let\makever\mymakever
  \tststile{}{}%
  \let\makever\oldmakever}
\newcommand{\mymakever}[4]
{% modified from \makever command
  \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
  \setlength\fboxrule{#2}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{s}}{%
    \rule[.5#3-\fboxrule]{#4}{#2}%
    \hspace*{-2\fboxrule}%
    \makebox[\fboxrule]{\rule[-.5#3]{#4}{#2}}%
    \rule[-0.5#3]{#2}{#3}%
  }{}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{d}}{\fbox{%
      \rule[-0.5#3+\fboxrule]{0pt}{#3-2\fboxrule}%
      \hspace{#4}%
      \rule[-0.5#3+\fboxrule]{0pt}{#3-2\fboxrule}%
    }}{}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{t}}{\fbox{%
      \rule[-0.5#3+\fboxrule]{0pt}{#3-2\fboxrule}%
      \hspace{#4}%
      \rule[-0.5#3+\fboxrule]{#2}{#3-2\fboxrule}%
      \hspace{#4}%
      \rule[-0.5#3+\fboxrule]{0pt}{#3-2\fboxrule}%
    }%
  }{}%
}

\begin{document}

$\sststile{}{}\; \mysststile$

$\dststile{}{}\; \mydststile$

$\tststile{}{}\; \mytststile$

\end{document}
```

[image: turnstile variations]

## EDIT

Correct heights so the vertical rules in the modified turnstiles match the height and depth of those in the originals for all three symbols, and ensure that the heights of the three are also equal (as a consequence).

Comment: This is what I am after, but I do not use the turnstyle package:

\documentclass[fleqn]{scrartcl}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\makeatletter\let\TTTemp\cap\makeatother
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{teubner}
\makeatletter\let\cap\TTTemp\makeatother
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{lgreek}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{mathtools}

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal OK. You don't have to use my solution, obviously. You have another answer available. My solution requires the `turnstile` package, as you rightly observe. I don't know why you would especially object to it, but if for some reason you don't want to use it, obviously my solution won't work for you. Nonetheless, it might be of use to somebody else with the same question and less finicky taste in packages, don't you think? That is, I can't see why this would not be a reasonable answer even if it is not a good solution for you personally. But I'm not sure if you are objecting or not.

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal I just tested with your extended preamble added and my solution works fine. I get just the same output, no errors. The only things I did was remove duplicate packages and the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, all of which are superfluous.

Comment: You are right that I may use the turnstyle package, of course. However, the turnstyles you define are three times the size as the ones I have with the MnSymbol package, and the proportions between the vertical and horisontal bars are also slightly different.

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal You can adjust the sizes using the package but probably at that point you are better off using a different approach. Not having any idea how you plan to use these makes it a bit difficult to guess what might work best. Note that it is `turnstile` - stile as in the things you cross when walking rather than style as in personal flair.